# How to avoid grant permissions at start of the app in flutter?

Tags: flutter

My flutter app has camera and voice permissions. It will be okay if these permission not be granted at start of the app, it make my app stuck with black screen.

How can I avoid these permissions to be granted at start of the app?

Comment: call request permission when you want to get permission. Remove it from on app start.

Comment: I didn't call it from on app start, it just auto grant permission popup

Comment: then you must be using some kind of plugin which triggers the request permission.

Answer (score 0):

You have the control to change where you want to request permission. If you don't want it at start of the app, move the code where you request permission to different screen.

Comment: I didn't request for permission from on start of the app, it just auto call it. I will try to use permission handler